# if $a < b$ then $a + c \leq b + c$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

$a, b, c$ are ordinals. Ordinal addition is defined as
$$a + b = type(\{0\}\times a\cup \{1\}\times b, L)$$
where L is the lexicographic ordering. Ordinal $a \leq b$ is defined as $a < b$ or $a = b$, where $<$ is defined by $\in$ relation.

I'm trying to prove that $a + c\leq b + c$ if $a < b$, but I'm having quite some trouble using the $\leq$ definition I was given here.

Comment: There's an obvious order-preserving injection from $a+c$ to $b+c$.

Comment: There is indeed, but is injection sufficient to show the $\leq$ relation here given I'm quite limited on the definition?

Comment: Yes, an order-preserving injection from ordinal $\alpha$ to ordinal $\beta$ establishes that $\alpha \leq \beta$.  That's probably something you can prove easily enough if you haven't already established it.  Use transfinite induction to modify the injection to use the smallest unused element of $\beta$ and you'll get an initial segment of $\beta$ (which may prove to be all of $\beta$, which is why the inequality isn't strict).